# Set width of td depending on No of td using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, width

I have several web pages with different amount of tables with different amount of columns.

I was looking on the net for a jquery spinet which gets the number of columns of the table and depending on the number of columns will define the width of each column.

Ex.

```
  if (noOfTdOnTable == 2) {
     tdWidth = "50%";
    }
    if (noOfTdOnTable == 3) {
      td1Width = "40%";
      td2Width = "40%";
      td3Width = "20%";
    }
    if (noOfTdOnTable == 4) {
      td1Width = "35%";
      td2Width = "25%";
      td3Width = "15%";
      td4Width = "15%";
    }
```

**Update**

Using the only answer I was given I have this at the moment but only works when there is one table on the page and I could not figure out how to apply when there are two columns.

```
        var num = $("table > td").length;


    if (num % 4 == 0) {
        $("table  > td:eq(0)").css("width", "50%");
        $("table > td:eq(1)").css("width", "30%");
        $("table > td:eq(2)").css("width", "10%");
        $("table > td:eq(3)").css("width", "10%");
    }
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
        $("table > td:eq(0)").css("width", "50%");
        $("table > td:eq(1)").css("width", "40%");
        $("table > td:eq(2)").css("width", "10%");
    }
```

This is an example of the html, but the code will apply to lots of pages with different No of Tables but all tables will have either 2,3 or 4 columns.

```
<html>    
    <table>
           <tr>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
          </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
           <tr>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
          </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
           <tr>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Dumb Question: Why don't you set the table cell widths directly in your HTML or CSS?

Comment: No so dump as the idea is to apply the code to 100's of pages already created with lots of tables and doing that with html or css would take a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the number of columns:

```
var num = $("#table > tr > td").length;
```

To specify the width:

```
$("#table > tr > td").width(w + "px");
```

I hope this was what you were looking for

**Edit:**

To specify the width to a specific column:

//if you've specified an id to each td

```
$("#td1").width(td1Width+"px");
```

//if you just use classes to identify them

```
$("td.td1", "#table1").width(td1Width+"px");
```

I would also recommend you to look into [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to select columns in an efficient way. since making a `$()` call is a more expensive operation:

```
$("#table1").find("#td1").width(td1Width+"px").end().find("#td2")...
```

**Edit 2**

try this instead

```
$("table > tr > td:eq(0)").css("width", "50%");
```

or even better

```
$("table > tr > td").eq(0).css("width", "50%").end()
                    .eq(1).css(...etc;
```

"table" will select all tables on the page; use id or class to identify which table you require.

**Edit 3 (final!!)**

Ok, now i can see all the code i can give a better answer. try this:

```
var num;
var $tds;
$("table").each(function(i, t) {
   $tds = $("td", t);
   num = $tds.length;

   if (num % 4 == 0) {
        $tds.eq(0).css("width", "50%").end()
            .eq(1).css("width", "30%").end()
            .eq(2).css("width", "10%").end()
            .eq(3).css("width", "10%");
    }
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
        //etc
    }
});
```

I hope this is a better answer :)

Comment: there would be a problem if there's  `rowspan`

Comment: @Mouhannad: Thanks for your answer. To set the width of the td, wouldn't that set the same width to all tds?

Comment: That is not working for me as it gets all tds on table and set same width for all td. But thanks anyway.

Comment: yes it would. i couldn't make it a more specific answer since you didn't share your html. so because i don't know your html structure i just made a general code. check my edit

Comment: @Mouhannad: Sorry you are right I did not put the html, the problem is that the code is generic to apply to several pages and they can have several tables or one, therefore I am not using classes or id I just need to go through each table, find the No of columns on the table and set the width of the columns for each table depending on the No of Columns. Thanks.

Comment: @Mouhannad:I like your Edit2 but for some reason can't get it to work.

Comment: @Mouhannad:There is a small problem, which is, How can I figure out how many columns does the table have? Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: @Mouhannad: Great! thanks a lot + 1 and Accepted solution :-).